# The current origin is not registered with the Google OAuth client

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I'm trying to signup with the @react-oauth/google but is it not allowing me to signup.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm also facing the same issue.